# Is IndentationError a syntax error in Python or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I have a simple question,

Is `IndentationError` a `SyntaxError` in Python or not?

I think it is not but since I am a beginner I would like to be sure. 
Are syntax errors only those which give me `SyntaxError` as a response in an interpreter? For example, if I type

```
3f = 22
```

I get

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So if there's something else (`IndentationErro`r etc), may it be a sub-type of `SyntaxError` or not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> issubclass(IndentationError, SyntaxError)
True
```

It means yes

More info [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) and [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass)

Answer (score 3):

Your example is a SyntaxError, because you can't have an identifier that starts with a number:

```
>>> 3f = 22
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    3f = 22
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


>>>     f3 = 22
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f3 = 22
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent


>>> def test():
... f3 = 22
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    f3 = 22
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

An IndentationError is a kind of SyntaxError, see the method resolution order in: help(IndentationError) and: http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndentationError

Valid identifiers:

```
test
test3
test_3
__3Test_3______
```

Invalid identifiers:

```
3f
333
33__
# Using any symbol other than: _
```

See also:

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers