# Is there a way to catch 'IndentationError' in Django?

Tags: django, django-errors

I want to catch each and every exception (including indentation error in views), where can I catch them all ?

I have written a middleware, it catches few exceptions and not all of them.

**Note:** `IndentationError` in the title is just an example, I want to catch each and every exception in the application.

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? A `SyntaxError` or `IndentationError` means you have basic problems with your code; and these should _never_ be "excepted" (that is caught and then processed manually). If you are trying to log errors in middleware, use an error service like [sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `IndentationError` was just an example. Sentry is a third party service and I don't want to use that. I have built my own custom error aggregation tool which aggregates errors from Django application. And yes even I know `SyntaxError` is something bad in the code, it was just an example of an exception there can be other exceptions too such as `ConnectionTimedOut` for external services etc.

Answer (score 2):

`IndentationError` is a `SyntaxError` and it would be a horrible idea to catch Syntax Errors. Code must be validated before it can be executed.

Check this question [Is IndentationError a syntax error in Python or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375513/is-indentationerror-a-syntax-error-in-python-or-not)

Also you can not caught `SyntaxError` unless that happens during an `eval`, `compile` etc. More information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856408/syntaxerror-inconsistency-in-python)

Comment: Yes I know that, IndentationError is a SyntaxError, it was just an example. The thing is I want to catch any kind of exception, it is possible if you connect to `django.core.signals.got_request_exception`.

Answer (score 1):

You can install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8.
It will make sure that that your project is following every pep8 standard .
It will also show you if any Indentation error.

Comment: I am going to do that but I want to know a method to catch all exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

After debugging I found that signals are sent to `django.core.signals.got_request_exception` for all exceptions that occur in Django i.e. we can catch all exceptions once we connect a function to that signal.